# Stripe in Laravel and Mobile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am working on a project about payments with stripe, I have done the Api for mobile with Laravel. I have also done a admin panel to watch and manage the data of the mobile. Now what I need to do is set payments for mobile stripe. Can u help me on the idea now, do i need to create Api for mobile to make payments like on a website stripe payments  or mobile can use stripe api and just post me the data for 'user_subscriptions' and than this data can be watched by my admin panel.
Thanks in advance for your time if you stop by!

Comment: You would need an API endpoint that creates subscriptions after you’ve taken a captured a charge with Stripe in your mobile app.

Comment: @MartinBean you mean that after mobile stripe payment is done i have to make a post api to take the data for my "user_subscriptions " and store in db?

Comment: Yes. That’s what something like [Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/master/billing) does under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webhooks for this for example once a payment is done Stripe Server will automatically call a API on your server with all the necessary data.